# How to restore metaclass on object to original class definition

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

I've been trying to create a TEMPORARY override on new objects, and then to remove the override on the objects themselves.  I'm not sure if this can be done, but here is what I've tried so far.

```
// Say I have a class like:
class Validator {
  boolean validate() { println "code here to return actual true/false"; false }
}

// I have two integration points one of them is Here before construction:

// First integration point:
// Save actual validate function
def realValidate = Validator.&validate
// Make new instances of Validator have the validate function hardwired to true
Validator.metaClass.validate { -> println "hardwired true"; true }

// Code I'd rather not modify
// Now some code executes which news up an instance and calls validate
def validator = new Validator()
validator.validate() // This correctly calls our override

// Second integration point.
// Without newing up a new Validator object, I'd like to remove the override.
Validator.metaClass = null

validator.metaClass.validate = Validator.&validate

// This throws "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class"
//validator.validate()

// So maybe I have to explicitly say:
realValidate.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST

// But this still throws the same exception
//validator.validate()

// Perhaps if I tell my objects metaclass to forget about validate, it will bubble up and look for the method on its declaring class?
validator.metaClass.validate = { -> throw new MissingMethodException("validate", Validator.class, (Object[])[], false) }

// This throws MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Validator.validate() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
//  Possible solutions: validate(), wait()
//validator.validate()
```

Apologies for not having a super specific question, since I don't know what all is possible in this particular area.  I'd love both the reason why my code doesn't work, as well as alternatives to make it work.

Comment: AFAIK, in the context of a Grails unit/integration test, simply setting the `metaClass` to null should restore the original metaclass, does this work?

Comment: @Dónal Setting the metaClass of `Validator` (the class) makes any new objects not have that override, but in my case, I'm working with an already constructed instance.  Setting the metaClass of `validator` (the object) doesn't do anything.

Comment: Ah, I was wrong, setting the metaClass to null DOES work, though you have to set *BOTH* the metaClass of the Class, and the metaClass of the object to null.  I tried each, and alone they don't work, but setting both of them does work!  Thanks for the inspiration @Dónal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a per instance meta class problem... Validator.metaClass = null will set the global meta class for the Validator class to default. but your validator instance here is a Groovy class and thus stores a separate reference to the meta class in the instance itself. Calls with that instance will not go through a lookup of the global meta class and instead use the per instance meta class (the reference stored in the instance itself). Thus validator.metaClass = null is the only way to reset this

Answer (score 0):

A small modification to your strategy would be fruitful. Use `metaClass` on the object instead of the Class.

```
// Say I have a class like:
class Validator {
  boolean validate() { println "code here to return actual true/false"; false }
}

def validator = new Validator()

// mark that the pointer is on object instead of class
def realValidate = validator.&validate

validator.metaClass.validate { -> println "hardwired true"; true }
validator.validate() // This correctly calls our override

// Second integration point.
// DO NOT NEED THIS
// validator.metaClass = null

// Assign the method pointer to validate to call original validate
validator.metaClass.validate = realValidate

validator.validate()
```

Your approach did not work because you had `validate()` overridden on the `metaClass` of Class reference instead of the object itself.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this and this would indeed work, but in my case Validator is complicated to build (not using DI), and so I don't have the reference to the object at the first integration point.

Comment: It does not matter. It can be done as lazily as possible. You would get validator object at one point of time, where you can do whatever is shown in the answer immediately after `new Validator()`. I am not sure if I am understanding otherwise.

Comment: In reality, validator takes in references to multiple objects that aren't yet available, is expensive to create, and does nasty-side-effecty things in the constructor.