# Groovy Expando Metaclass setter access

Tags: groovy

I have the following tests written with a dummy Employee groovy class.

```
@Test
void returnPropertyIfPropertyIsAvailableOnMetaClass(){
    def emp=new Employee()
    emp.metaClass.sayGutenAbend="Guten Abend"
    assert emp.sayGutenAbend=="Guten Abend"
    assert emp.sayGutenAbend==emp.metaClass.getProperty(emp,"sayGutenAbend")
    emp.metaClass.setProperty(emp,"sayGutenAbend","Guten Morgen")
    assert emp.sayGutenAbend=="Guten Morgen"
    assert emp.sayGutenAbend==emp.metaClass.getProperty(emp,"sayGutenAbend");
}
```

The above test passes while the below fails-

```
@Test
void returnPropertyIfPropertyIsAvailableOnMetaClass_Fails(){
    def emp=new Employee()
    emp.metaClass.sayGutenAbend="Guten Abend"
    assert emp.sayGutenAbend=="Guten Abend"
    assert emp.sayGutenAbend==emp.metaClass.getProperty(emp,"sayGutenAbend")
    emp.metaClass.sayGutenAbend="Guten Morgen"
    assert emp.sayGutenAbend=="Guten Morgen"
    assert emp.sayGutenAbend==emp.metaClass.getProperty(emp,"sayGutenAbend")
}
```

The only difference from the previous code sample being, setting a new value for the same property on the metaclass. Just curious. Could anyone point me to why this is working this way?

Answer (score 1):

Once the field is created with metaprogramming you don't need to reset it using `metaClass`:

```
class Employee{}

def emp = new Employee()

emp.metaClass.sayGutenAbend="Guten Abend"
assert emp.sayGutenAbend=="Guten Abend"
assert emp.sayGutenAbend==emp.metaClass.getProperty(emp,"sayGutenAbend")

emp.sayGutenAbend="Guten Nacht"
assert emp.sayGutenAbend=="Guten Nacht"
assert emp.sayGutenAbend==emp.metaClass.getProperty(emp,"sayGutenAbend")
```

I'm taking a wild guess that this happens due to some part of the metaclass being recreated, while what you wanted is to change the one binded to your object instance. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27963934) might be related.

---

In this snippet, resetting the property creates a new `ThreadManagedMetaBeanProperty`, thus, this fails:

```
class Employee{}

def emp = new Employee()
emp.metaClass.sayGutenAbend="Guten Abend"

def metaclass1 = emp.metaClass.properties[1]
emp.metaClass.sayGutenAbend="Guten Nacht"

def metaclass2 = emp.metaClass.properties[1]

assert metaclass1 == metaclass2 // fails
```

Whilst this works:

```
class Employee{}

def emp = new Employee()
emp.metaClass.sayGutenAbend="Guten Abend"

def metaclass1 = emp.metaClass.properties[1]
emp.sayGutenAbend="Guten Nacht"

def metaclass2 = emp.metaClass.properties[1]

assert metaclass1 == metaclass2 // works
```